# CSS nth-child apply odd-even rule but switch every 4 items

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of `divs` that appear 4 in a row with a class and I would like to create a checkerboard background style, meaning:

- Apply a different background color for odd and even `divs`
- Switch the odd-even to even-odd for each line

I've tried this

```css
.boxwrapper:nth-child(2n-1), .boxwrapper:nth-child(2n) {
    background:#ff0000;
}
.boxwrapper:nth-child(4n-2), .boxwrapper:nth-child(4n-3) {
    background:#0000ff;
}
```

and it works fine for odd-even divs but cant get it to switch every 4 items. I'm headaching over the 4n-1, 4n+1 stuff, if I could get that right voila!

The result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, forgot the code in my original post. Updated now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/mykhA/1/

#### HTML

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```css
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.line {
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
}

.box {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
}

.box:nth-child(8n+2) {
    background-color: red;
}

.box:nth-child(8n+4) {
    background-color: red;
}
.box:nth-child(8n+5) {
    background-color: red;
}

.box:nth-child(8n+7) {
    background-color: red;
}

.box:nth-child(8n+1) {
    background-color: blue;
}

.box:nth-child(8n+3) {
    background-color: blue;
}

.box:nth-child(8n+6) {
    background-color: blue;
}

.box:nth-child(8n) {
    background-color: blue;
}
​
```

​

Comment: I get your point but I dont know if I can add <div class"line"> every 4 elements. The divs are in fact, results of a recordset and are populated dynamically.

Comment: I edited my post so now it works without additional markup http://jsfiddle.net/mykhA/1/

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to get the elements in only 2 styles but I see now that I needed more. Simple is, indeed, always the best approach!

Answer (score 0):

Just after the solution from @Miszy, I also found a jQuery solution that does the same thing regardless of how many divs will appear on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(.boxwrapper:nth-child(8n+3), .boxwrapper:nth-child(8n+5), .boxwrapper:nth-child(8n+8), .boxwrapper:nth-child(8n+10)").css({"background-color":"red"});
});
```

Either one will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use only 4 selectors to switch the background-color. (answer  similar to @MichałMiszczyszyn => shorter approach)

The repeating pattern goes on 2 rows of 4 elements, the choice of `:nth-child(8n)` is indeed the basic pattern to work on, example :

```
:nth-child(8n-1),
:nth-child(8n-3),
:nth-child(8n-6),
:nth-child(8n-12){
background:/* switch to the other value here */;
}
```

```css
.square {
  width:25%;
  margin:auto;
  background:turquoise;
  counter-reset:div;
  overflow:hidden; /* to deal with float */
}

.square div {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  text-align:center;
  background:green;
}
.square div:nth-child(8n-1),
.square div:nth-child(8n-3),
.square div:nth-child(8n-6),
.square div:nth-child(8n-12){
background:tomato;
}

/* demo purpose */
body:hover div div {
background:initial;/* resets to none to show parents background */
}
.square div:before {
  content:'';
  padding-top:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.square div:after {
  counter-increment:div;
  content:counter(div);
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-size:2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="square">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The pattern will repeat itself every 8 elements.

Notice that you can spare the initial `background-color` of squares and use the parent background.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a responsive version of css checkerboard (damier) from 1 per ligne to 5 per line.

http://jsfiddle.net/Choufourax/pb09o5fa/1/

CSS

```
div.grid {
  display: grid;
}
div.grid > div {
    color: red;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
    /* comment these 3 lines if you don't need to center content */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* Default => 1 per ligne */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)   {
  
  div.grid > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

/* 50%  => 2 per ligne */
@media only screen and (max-width: 840px) and (min-width: 600px)  {
  div.grid {
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
  }
  div.grid > div:nth-child(4n+1), div.grid > div:nth-child(4n+4) {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

/* 33%  => 3 per ligne */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 840px)  {
  div.grid {
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  }
  div.grid > div:nth-child(6n+1), div.grid > div:nth-child(6n+3), div.grid > div:nth-child(6n+5)  {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

/* 25% => 4 per ligne */ 
@media only screen and (max-width: 1140px) and (min-width: 1024px)  {
  div.grid {
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  }
  div.grid > div:nth-child(8n+1), div.grid > div:nth-child(8n+3), div.grid > div:nth-child(8n+6), div.grid > div:nth-child(8n+8) {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

/* 20% => 5 per ligne */ 
@media only screen and (min-width: 1141px)  {
  div.grid {
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  }
  div.grid > div:nth-child(10n+1), div.grid > div:nth-child(10n+3), div.grid > div:nth-child(10n+5), div.grid > div:nth-child(10n+7), div.grid > div:nth-child(10n+9) {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

Html :

```
<div class="grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
```